Analytic continuation Matsubara/imaginary-time to retarded function in complex time domain
In linear response theory, one may either use the real-time retarded correlation function, or analytically continue to imaginary time/frequency to use the Matsubara Green's function instead. While this is typically done in the frequency domain, I was hoping to show it entirely in the time domain.
Specifically, we have the integrated correlator as shown below.
Case 1: Deform the integration contour from $\beta\to 0$ along the imaginary time axis to negative infinity, as evident from the limits of the integrals written below.
$$\begin{align}\int_\beta^0\langle d\tau \mathcal{T}_\tau A(t)B(t+i\tau) \rangle = &\int_0^{-\infty}d\zeta \langle A(t)B(t+i\beta+\zeta) \rangle+\underbrace{\int_\beta^0\langle d\tau  A(t)B(t+\lambda+i\tau)\vert_{\lambda\to-\infty}}_{\to 0}+\int_{-\infty}^0 d\zeta \langle A(t)B(t+\zeta) \rangle\\ 
=&\int_{-\infty}^0 d\zeta \Big(-\underbrace{\langle A(t)B(t+i\beta+\zeta) \rangle}_{=\langle B(t+\zeta)A(t) \rangle,\ (\text{Kubo-Martin-Schwinger})}+\langle A(t)B(t+\zeta) \rangle\Big)\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^t dt'\langle [A(t),B(t')] \rangle=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt'g^{ret.}_{A,B}(t-t') 
\end{align} $$
Case 2: Deform the integration contour from $\beta\to 0$ along the imaginary time axis to positive infinity, as evident from the limits of the integrals written below.
$$\begin{align}\int_\beta^0\langle d\tau \mathcal{T}_\tau A(t)B(t+i\tau) \rangle = &\int_0^{\infty}d\zeta \langle A(t)B(t+i\beta+\zeta) \rangle+\underbrace{\int_\beta^0\langle d\tau  A(t)B(t+\lambda+i\tau)\vert_{\lambda\to+\infty}}_{\to 0}+\int_{\infty}^0 d\zeta \langle A(t)B(t+\zeta) \rangle\\ 
=&\int_0^{\infty} d\zeta \Big(\underbrace{\langle A(t)B(t+i\beta+\zeta) \rangle}_{=\langle B(t+\zeta)A(t) \rangle,\ (\text{Kubo-Martin-Schwinger})}-\langle A(t)B(t+\zeta) \rangle\Big)\\
=&-\int_t^{\infty} dt'\langle [A(t),B(t')] \rangle=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt'g^{adv.}_{A,B}(t-t') 
\end{align} $$
$\mathcal{T}_\tau$ denotes the time-ordering operator along the imaginary time axis, for which I use the variable $\tau$. The subscripts $ret.$ and $adv.$ denote the retarded and advanced components.
Case 1 is what is typically encountered. This is usually proven by Fourier transforming the integrand/susceptibility. Case 2 is wrong because it clearly breaks causality. The response at time t can not depend on the future. Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong in case 2?
